# How do I modify this socket code to be able to print any .txt URL that was input by the user?

Tags: python, sockets

My professor gave us this python socket code to work with that we need to modify to be able to accept any .txt URL from user input and print out the text from that web page. The arguments within the **mysock.connect()** and **mysock.sendall()** were already hard coded into them by the professor. The http printed information from the webpage such as the content type, content length, etc. are okay to be printed too.

In the user input portion of the assignment, my professor also requires we wrote code for a try/except block to "*handle the condition where the user enters an improperly formatted or non-existent URL*". I left a couple comments clarifying the regular expressions and the return statement. But I am not sure how to modify the professor's block of socket code to accept URLs from user input. Here is an example URL from a .txt webpage the professor would like the text printed from as user input: http://www.gutenberg.org/files/65083/65083-0.txt

Thank you for reading!

```
import re

# the ' \. ' represents the preceding period in the top level domain
# the ' ... ' represents the 3 letter top level domain
# return statement is indexed to zeroth element to extract 'www.domain_name.org' portion of URL 

def url_validation(myInput):
    try:
        re.findall('http://(.*\....)/', myInput)
        valid_url = re.findall('http://(.*\....)/', myInput)
        print('The url slice is', valid_url[0])
        return valid_url[0]

    except:
        print('Error: Please use a valid URL')

#User Input

myInput = input('Please enter any URL: ')

valid_URL = url_validation(myInput)

#Proffesor's Socket Code 

import socket

mysock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
mysock.connect(('data.pr4e.org', 80))

mysock.sendall(b'GET http://data.pr4e.org/romeo.txt HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n')


while True:
    data = mysock.recv(300)
    if (len(data) < 1):
        break
    print(data.decode(),end='')
print("")
mysock.close()
```

Comment: Why are you calling `re.findall()` twice? The first one is useless, since you don't use its result.

Comment: The capture group in the regexp contains the hostname you want to connect to. Use that in the `mysock.connect()` argument.